# How do you add 1 every second?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have tried everything, I can't do it!!!
Here's my code please help:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
         <head>
              <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico"/>
              <title>Doughtnut Box !</title>
              <!--Design-->
              <style>

              </style>
              <!--jQuery and Javascript-->
              <script>
                 var doughnut = 0;
                   window.setInterval(
                        doughnut + 1
                   ,1000);
                   document.getElementById("doughnuts").innerHTML="You have " + doughnut >+ " doughnuts!";
              </script>
         </head>
         <body>
              <h3 id="doughnuts"></h3>
         </body></html>
```

Thanks for the code, it was really great!  Now how can I save it so that it won't start over when I refresh?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Put them in a function. Also, **change your expression to an assignment**.

```
<script>
     var doughnut = 0;
     window.setInterval(
     function () {
         doughnut = doughnut + 1;
         document.getElementById("doughnuts").innerHTML = "You have " + doughnut + " doughnuts!";

     }, 1000);
</script>
```

Runnable demo below:

```js
var doughnut = 0;
window.setInterval(function () {
  doughnut = doughnut + 1;
  document.getElementById("doughnuts").innerHTML = "You have " + doughnut + " doughnuts!";
}, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="doughnuts"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works great, I don't know more than the basics at html, javascript, and css.

Comment: what's an expression and what's an assignment?

Comment: An assignment is when you set (assign) a value to a variable. Such as in `var myVariableName = <value here>;`. Now the value can be an expression, such as two integers like `1+1`, or a string like `'John'`, including or not another another variable such as in `doughtnut + 1`. Does it make sense to you?

Answer (score 2):

`setInterval` accepts function or quoted code.
Try that:

```
<script>
var doughnut = 0;
window.setInterval(function(){
    doughnut++;
    document.getElementById("doughnuts").innerHTML = "You have " + doughnut + " doughnuts!";
}, 1000);
</script>
```

Comment: `doughnut + 1` will not increment `doughnut` (the incremented value is not stored anywhere and is therefore lost).

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi true :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var doughnut = 0;
window.setInterval( 
function()
{
    document.getElementById("doughnuts").innerHTML="You have " + ++doughnut + " doughnuts!";
 }
                   ,1000);
```

Comment: @Liam It's the javascript increment operator : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators . You could replace it with doughnut = doughnut+ 1, but this is shorter.

Comment: Oh, didn't realise you could reverse it. Well that's worth a +1

Comment: @Liam actually, there's a difference between ++x and x++. ++x Will first increment, then evaluate, x++ will first evaluate, then increment. So if x = 3, ++x will return 4, but x++ will return 3.

Comment: @some It's a mistake, edited, thanks for spotting it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

[DEMO Here.](http://jsfiddle.net/q2Fv3/1/)

```
var doughnut = 0;
//show 0 for the first time
show_value();
//start counter
setInterval(function(){
    doughnut += 1;
    show_value();        
}, 1000);
function show_value(){
    document.getElementById("doughnuts").innerHTML = "You have " + doughnut + " doughnuts!";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way which count the time to do the function.

This case is not relevant but it may be usefull under certains circumptances.

```
var doughnut = 0;

function show_value()
{
    document.getElementById("doughnuts").innerHTML = "You have " + doughnut++ + " doughnuts!";
    setTimeout(show_value, 1000);
}

show_value();
```

Comment: Better use `setTimeout(show_value, 1000)` instead of `setTimeout(function() { show_value(); }, 1000);`